# BMP file formats and edge detection

Tags: c, image

I came across this excellent tutorial on image processing by Bill Green - http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/alumni/bGreen/www.pages.drexel.edu/_weg22/edge.html

He works with BMP formats in the tutorial since they are the simplest. I tried the sobel edge detection code, got it to compile and run. When I try this on the images on that web site (for example, LIAG.bmp, the photo of the lady), the code works just fine. However, when I get other .bmp images (for example, take any image and convert it at - http://www.online-convert.com/result/6c0ce763b5e6cadf3a76a966acdb9505) and the code spits out an image that can't be read by any image editor. The issue is most probably in the line -

```
nColors = (int)getImageInfo(bmpInput, 46, 4);
```

of his code. There seems to be some hard coding here which only works on the image sizes on his tutorial. The nColors variable is 256 for all images on his site, but 0 for all images I get otherwise. Can any one tell me how I might change this piece of code to generalize this?

Comment: Did you try making 256-colour bitmaps?  That link to `online-convert.com` downloaded a picture of some mountains as a BMP file, but it's in 24-bit colour (16+ million colours).

Comment: I think that's the problem. Is there a way to convert a given image to a 256 color bitmap?

Comment: Paint lets you save files as 256 color bitmaps. I tried that, but the images still don't produce edge images that open.

Comment: Have you considered using an OS-supplied library to read the images in so you don't have to be concerned with image format? For example, on MacOS, there's CoreGraphics, AVFoundation, QuickTime, etc. I assume that Windows and Linux and other OSes have similar libraries, too. If you can abstract away the file format from the concept of an image, you can do a lot more.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the point of using .bmp's was that they could be hacked around (I wanted some really simple code with minimum or no dependencies). But apparently even they are too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The `46` in this line:

```
nColors = (int)getImageInfo(bmpInput, 46, 4);
```

...refers to the bit offset into the header of the BMP.   Unless you are creating BMPs that do not use this file structure it should theoretically work. He is referring to 8-bit images on that page.  Perhaps, 16 or 32-bit images use a different file structure for the header.

Read this Wikipedia page for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure